# Getting error while adding service reference in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, service, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add service refence in my application in visual studio. But i am getting error "value cannot be null.Parameter name:machineConfigFileName.

So,I thought there is something wrong with the service. That's why i created my own sample wcf service and tried adding service refernce of this sample wcf service to my sample client app.But there aslo i am getting the same error.

I tested this in different machines and it is working fine in other machines.So, this means there is something wrong with my machine, but i am not sure what. Please help me in resolving this issue.

[image: Adding Service Reference Error]

Answer (score 0):

I have mention below link please follow and create the wcf service

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-wcf-services-using-jquery/

Hope is it helpfull for you

Comment: This question is related to the adding service reference and not calling a wcf service using jquery

Answer (score 0):

There might be a case that machine.config is not found while adding a service reference, install respective .net framework again and try adding the service reference again.